# How do I set the AWS peering connection DNS resolution options through CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have two VPCs:

- VPC1 which holds our RDS instance.
- VPC2 which holds our cluster of EC2 instances.

We have successfully setup a VPC peering connection, routes and security groups to allow appropriate communication.

In order to resolve the RDS instance AZ-appropriate local IP address from it's hostname, we need to follow [these instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/modify-peering-connections.html) and set `--requester-peering-connection-options AllowDnsResolutionFromRemoteVpc=true`.

If I do this manually through the AWS Console or the AWS CLI it all works fine, however I'm creating the cluster of EC2 instances through CloudFormation and the option is missing from the [CloudFormation documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpcpeeringconnection.html).

The effect of this is that my stack starts up and fails because the services themselves cannot connect to the database.

Am I doing something obvious wrong, or is this just Amazon being incomplete?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to add the following properties to cloud formation template when you are creating the VPCPeeringConection        
        "myVPCPeeringConnection": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection",
            "Properties": {
                "VpcId": {"Ref": "myVPC"},
                "PeerVpcId": {"Ref": "myPrivateVPC"},
                "AllowDnsResolutionFromRemoteVpc":"true",
                "RequesterPeeringConnectionOptions":"Allow"
            }
        }

Comment: I tried a number of permutations, as translated from the documentation for the AWS CLI, including AllowDnsResolutionFromRemoteVpc and RequesterPeeringConnectionOptions. In all cases the stack was rolled back with something like this:

"10:23:16 UTC+0100 CREATE_FAILED AWS::EC2::VPCPeeringConnection databasePeeringConnection Encountered unsupported property AllowDnsResolutionFromRemoteVpc".

If there is an undocumented property, I've not hit upon it in a trial an error combination yet.

Comment: Then there are two options left make an API call via the init.d script when the instance boots up or use an automation tool like Ansible to run a custom command to create VPC peering

Comment: Those two properties don't seem to work. It doesn't look like its supported in the docs. You probably need to add it in PC settings.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the frequency of updates, there are many times where an AWS feature isn't available in CloudFormation (ALB targeting Lambda used to be) - you end up having to create a custom resource to manage it.  It's not too bad, just make sure that your lambda responds with success or failure in *all* scenarios, including exceptions, otherwise your stack will be 'in progress' for hours.

Comment: I ended up moving to Terraform.

Comment: Here we are at the end of 2019 and it still doesn't seem to be exposed through CloudFormation...

Comment: I know, right!? 4 full years and they can't add 2 optional parameters that are true/false to manage it.

Comment: Still not exposed in 2022! geesh, this is a real problem, no reason to let certain things languish like this...